# How disable python precompile in rpm-maven-plugin?

Tags: python, maven, rpm

The rpm-maven-plugin generate implicit procompiled files. I don't need this files and this new files stop my rpm-generation, because these files not in automatic in my rpm SPEC.
Soulution 
https://www.redhat.com/archives/rpm-list/2007-November/msg00020.html
don't help me in my maven context!

Comment: Did you take a look at [that solution](https://github.com/zyegfryed/monitoring/blob/master/vmusage/rpm/pom.xml#L133-L143)? It empties `RPM_BUILD_ROOT` variable in an `installScriptlet`.

Comment: Not bad! But not so clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is redefine __os_install_post macro in pom.xml:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>rpm-maven-plugin</artifactId>    
        <version>2.1-alpha-1</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <name>${project.name}</name>
          <version>1.1</version>
          <release>111</release>
          <distribution>Red Hat 6.2 Enterprise Server</distribution>
          <group>Application/Media</group>
          <defineStatements>
            <defineStatement>__os_install_post
               /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-compress
    %{!?__debug_package:
    /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip %{__strip}
    /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip-comment-note %{__strip} %{__objdump}
    }
    /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip-static-archive %{__strip}
    /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-python-hardlink
            </defineStatement>
          </defineStatements>
```

The original macro is:

```
 rpm --showrc 

-14: __os_install_post
    /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-compress
    %{!?__debug_package:/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip %{__strip}}
    /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip-static-archive %{__strip}
    /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip-comment-note %{__strip} %{__objdump}
    /usr/lib/rpm/brp-python-bytecompile
    /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-python-hardlink
    %{!?__jar_repack:/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-java-repack-jars}
%{nil}
```

Comment: A a less fragile way to define this is  `__os_install_post %(echo '%{__os_install_post}' | sed -e 's!/usr/lib[^[:space:]]*/brp-python-bytecompile[[:space:]].*$!!g')` which edits the line out of the macro at build time.

Comment: The dynamic macro edit works, but adds the following error in the logging: "error: Too many levels of recursion in macro expansion. It is likely caused by recursive macro declaration."

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this was to use the following:

> ```
>                 <defineStatements>
>                     <defineStatement>_unpackaged_files_terminate_build 0</defineStatement>
>                 </defineStatements>
> ```

After changing this, I now get a *warning* about "Installed (but unpackaged) file(s) found" instead of an *error*, and my build continues.